# Python Anywhere issue using Urllib2 with virtualenv

Tags: python, django, urllib2, pythonanywhere

I'm using a Django server on [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com), using a virtualenv. In the server I'm using a scraping code to write a text file, the code uses urllib2 which should come bundled in python by default but there are various errors :

```
pip install urllib2
```

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib2 (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for urllib2

```
apt-get install python-urllib2
```

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission
>   denied) E: Unable to lock the administration directory
>   (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Of course the root of the issue is this (from python console) :

```
import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

Comment: slightly off-topic, but if you haven't come across it before, you should check out [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), a really nice library for doing http stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) is part of the standard library. You don't have to install it with pip or your package manager, it is already part of your Python 2 installation.

The pip command fails because there is no external package urllib2 to install.

The apt-get command fails because you do not have the correct permissions. Even if you used sudo or switched to root, it would fail because Python-urllib2 does not exist.

If you are using Python 3, the urllib2 module no longer it exists, and has been split between `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`. You need to update your code to use the new `urllib` module in Python 3.

Comment: Sounds like you might be using Python 3, in which case urllib2 does not exist. See my updated answer.